# How to join two pathlib.PosixPath paths into one?

Tags: python, join, path, operating-system, pathlib

I have problem with joining paths using other methods than just adding then together.

Python version: 3.9.0

Description of task:

> The user gives the path (`/path/to/some/folder`), the script found a file in a subfolder of that path (`subfolder/filename.ext`), but with the wrong extension (`ext`).
>
> Change the file extension to the correct one (`tex`) and copy it to the new path (`/some/other/path/to/folder`) keeping the folder structure (`folder/subfolder/`) in the path specified by the user (`/path/to/some/folder`).

Anyone know where I made a bug?

```py
import os
from pathlib import Path

input_path = Path('/path/to/some/folder')
file_found_in_input_path = Path('/path/to/some/folder/subfolder/filename.ext')
output_path = Path('/some/other/path/to/folder')
expected = Path('/some/other/path/to/folder/subfolder/filename.tex')
relative_path_to_found_file = Path(str(file_found_in_input_path).replace(str(input_path), '')).with_suffix('.tex')

result = output_path / relative_path_to_found_file                  # Doesn't work
# result = Path.joinpath(output_path, relative_path_to_found_file)  # Doesn't work
# result = os.path.join(output_path, relative_path_to_found_file)   # Doesn't work
# result = f'{output_path}{relative_path_to_found_file}'            # It worked...

print(f'   file_found_in_input_path: {file_found_in_input_path}')
print(f'relative_path_to_found_file: {relative_path_to_found_file}')
print(f'                     result: {result}')
print(f'                   expected: {expected}')
```

Output:

```
   file_found_in_input_path: /path/to/some/folder/subfolder/filename.ext
relative_path_to_found_file: /subfolder/filename.tex
                     result: /subfolder/filename.tex
                   expected: /some/other/path/to/folder/subfolder/filename.tex
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `relative_path_to_found_file` is `/subfolder/filename.tex`, so it is absolute path in os.path.join opinion.

You need to remove the first '/' from the relative_path_to_found_file, and you will get the right result.

```
print("wrong = ", os.path.join("/some/other/path/to/folder", "/subfolder/filename.tex"))
print("correct = ", os.path.join("/some/other/path/to/folder", "subfolder/filename.tex"))
```

```
wrong =  /subfolder/filename.tex
correct =  /some/other/path/to/folder/subfolder/filename.tex
```

Comment: Thanks for the information. I did not expect this to affect the operation of the code :)

Comment: @8TM, if this can solve your problem, you cab mark this answer as an answer)